# SharePoint 2019 on premise - Save list as template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, 2019, list-template

In previous versions of SharePoint you were able to save a list / library as a template. This function has been removed.

Is there any PowerShell command that I can use or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This function hasn't been removed in SharePoint 2019. I just did a test in my SharePoint 2019, I could see this function in my team site.

Besides, you could use the below powershell to save list template:

```
$WebURL="http://sp19/sites/michael"
$ListName="List1"
$TemplateName="Test Template"
$TemplateFileName="Test Template"
$TemplateDescription="List Template"
$SaveData = $true
 
#Get the Web and List objects
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.Lists[$ListName]
 
#Save List as Template
$List.SaveAsTemplate($TemplateFileName, $TemplateName, $TemplateDescription, $SaveData)
Write-Host "List Saved as Template!"
```

Comment: Mine is on premise - it is not visible. Is the feature still in the same place under the settings? It does make me now think it may need to be activated. Either way - thanks Michael. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Just another question about the code above - $SaveData = $True, does this save the data from the list being saved as a template?

Comment: Just tested again, the "save a list / library as a template" only missed in communication sites. In team sites, it worked well. I think you are using communication site.

Comment: $SaveData = $True means Include content. It will save the data from the original list.

Comment: Good to know - I will leave off the $SaveData where needed. And yes - communication site is what we have - thanks Michael

Comment: You are welcome. If my reply helps you, you could accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PnP Powershell. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

SharePoint artefacts can be exported as provisioning templates and these templates can be applied to other sites.

Create a template from an existing list - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps

Apply a template - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Hi teylyn - thanks for the answer. I am not experienced in PS so I will have to unpack it.