# SharePoint 2019 on premise - Delete list as template from apps

Tags: list, app, template

I have several list I no longer need which were created with some PS script. I need to know how to delete them now to clean up the listings. Any help always appreciated.

Script used
[SharePoint 2019 on premise - Save list as template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283701/sharepoint-2019-on-premise-save-list-as-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Delete List Template in SharePoint using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/delete-list-template-in-sharepoint-with-powershell.html)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Variables for Site URL and List template name
$SiteURL="https://intranet.crescent.com/sites/sales/"
$ListTemplateName ="Project Health.stp"
 
#Get Site and List Template Folder objects
$site = Get-SPSite $SiteURL
$ListTemplateFolder = $site.RootWeb.GetFolder("_catalogs/lt")
 
#Find the Specific List template and delete
$ListTemplate = $ListTemplateFolder.Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ListTemplateName }
 
if($ListTemplate)
{
    $ListTemplate.Recycle()
    #To permanently delete, call: $ListTemplate.delete();
    write-output "Deleted List template!"
}
```